# Unable to retrieve data from firebase database due to async nature of firebase dabase

Tags: android, asynchronous, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My ArrayList Seems to be empty when i try to retrieve data for first time due to async nature of firebase API,with second attempt to load data Its loaded properly,here is code related to the same.
Method which is used to retrieve data

```
    AdvertisementRef.orderByChild("Category").equalTo(categoryS).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                SaveAddInformation mModel = eventSnapshot.getValue(SaveAddInformation.class);
                Log.d("DATA" ,""+ mModel);
                adinfolist.add(mModel);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });


    return adinfolist;

}
```

MainActivity

```
     rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    advertismentref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ADVERTISEMENT INFORMATION");
    helper=new Firebase_helper(advertismentref);
    adapter=new AdvertisementAdapter(helper.retrieve(/*catS*/),this);
    // adapter  = new AdvertisementAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ViewHolder and Adapter Classes

```
public class AdvertisementAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <AdvertisementAdapter.AdvetisementViewHolder>{
ArrayList<SaveAddInformation>saveAddInformations=new ArrayList<SaveAddInformation>();
Context ctx;

public AdvertisementAdapter(ArrayList<SaveAddInformation> saveAddInformations,Context ctx) {
    this.saveAddInformations = saveAddInformations;
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
public AdvertisementAdapter.AdvetisementViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.design_row,parent,false);
    AdvetisementViewHolder myViewholder=new AdvetisementViewHolder(v,ctx,saveAddInformations);

    return myViewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdvertisementAdapter.AdvetisementViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SaveAddInformation save=saveAddInformations.get(position);
    String title=save.getTitleS();
    holder.titleTv.setText(title);
    String rentamt=save.getRent_amount();
    holder.rentamt.setText(rentamt);
    String rentdays=save.getRentDaysSpin();
    holder.rentdays.setText(rentdays);
    String description=save.getProductDetails();
    holder.desc.setText(description);
    String imguri=save.getImageuri();

    holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), imguri);



}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return saveAddInformations.size();
}


public static class AdvetisementViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView titleTv,rentamt,rentdays,desc;
    Context ctx;
    ImageView adimg;
    ArrayList<SaveAddInformation>saveAddInformations=new ArrayList<SaveAddInformation>();

    public AdvetisementViewHolder(View itemView,Context ctx,ArrayList<SaveAddInformation>saveAddInformations) {


        super(itemView);
        this.saveAddInformations=saveAddInformations;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.ctx=ctx;


        titleTv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Titletextv);

        rentamt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rent_amount);
        rentdays=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.days_rent);
        desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);




    }

    public void setImage(Context applicationContext, String imguri) {

        adimg=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_image);

        // We Need TO pass Context

        Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(imguri).into(adimg);

    }
```

Comment: you can use interface for same when u get data in just update adapter using interface

Answer (score 2):

I have just moved retrieve method into main activity and called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onDataChange and onCancelled method and it worked!!!